# Calculation cross entropy for batch of two tensors

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, cross-entropy

I’d like to calculate cross entropy for batch of two tensors:

```
x = torch.tensor([[[ 2.1137, -1.3133,  0.7930,  0.3330,  0.9407],
        [-0.8380, -2.0299, -1.1218,  0.3150,  0.4797],
        [-0.7439,  0.0753, -0.1121,  0.0096, -1.2621]]])

y = torch.tensor([[1,2,3]])
    ​
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(x, y)

​
```

but receive exception:

```
RuntimeError: Expected target size [1, 5], got [1, 3]
```

Please explain what is wrong…

Answer (score 0):

your x has 5 elements in list and your y has 3 elements, the target size has to match

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
x = torch.tensor([[[ 2.1137, -1.3133,  0.7930,  0.3330,  0.9407],
        [-0.8380, -2.0299, -1.1218,  0.3150,  0.4797],
        [-0.7439,  0.0753, -0.1121,  0.0096, -1.2621]]])
y = torch.tensor([[1,2,2,2,2]])
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(x, y)
```

Also, your model will output tensor of shape [,2]. This is passed to CrossEntropyLoss,
so your targets must be a tensor of shape [,2]

One of your target labels has value 3, so you will get an error. same with 4 and 5

You need to add more layer of tensors to x. for 3 you just need to add 1 more.

Heres an example if you want to have value 5.

```
x = torch.tensor([[[ 2.1137, -1.3133,  0.7930,  0.3330,  0.9407],
        [-0.8380, -2.0299, -1.1218,  0.3150,  0.4797],
        [-0.7439,  0.0753, -0.1121,  0.0096, -1.2621],
        [-0.7439,  0.0753, -0.1121,  0.0096, -1.2621],               
        [-0.7439,  0.0753, -0.1121,  0.0096, -1.2621],
        [-0.7439,  0.0753, -0.1121,  0.0096, -1.2621]]])
y = torch.tensor([[1,2,3,4,5]])
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(x, y)
```

I hope this puts the pieces for you together on the relationship of x and y.